# Node hidden in overlapping nodes in scatter plot in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I have created a scatter plot in R as (it is a linear regression plot in which two vectors having 200+ values are plotted against each other)

[image: It is a linear regression plot in which two vectors having 200+ values are plotted against each other]

I want the encircled "red node" on "position 1" to be completely seen like "red" node on position 2 on "green nodes" as it is a point of interest.
This is the code.

```
y <- c(0.04229, 0.0277, 0.04071, 0.02299, 0.04227, 0.07279, 0.04278, 0.08241, 0.04271, 0.07724, 0.02991, 0.02442, 0.04292, 0.04984, 0.04214, 0.02872, 0.02792, 0.02277, 0.02722, 0.04002, 0.00417, 0.02877, 0.01777, 0.0281, 0.02988, 0.01274, 0.04877, 0.02802, 0.07798, 0.00499, 0.00749, 0.0429, 0.04271, 0.0227, 0.00912, 0.00917, 0.01208, 0.02482, 0.02784, 0.01497, -0.0024, 0.0228, 0.0271, -0.00027, 0.04741, 0.0148, 0.04124, 0.00129, -0.00484, 0.0291, 0.02472, 0.00992, 0.00024, 0.00924, -0.00298, 0.00477, 0.02877, 0.02229, 0.00281, 0.00978, 0.01448, 0.0217, 0.02442, 0.02227, 0.0101, 0.01724, 0.02497, 0.02114, 0.00774, 0.00784, 0.00718, 0.00449, 0.00414, 0.01224, 0.02871, 0.04477, 0.01747, 0.07418, 0.02849, 0.07287, 0.00797, 0.01272, 0.01027, 0.02184, 0.01792, 0.00784, 0.01487, 0.00842, 0.01849, 0.04042, 0.00278, 0.02271, 0.01087, 0.04297, 0.01019, 0.02027, 0.0277, 0.04424, 0.02709, 0.00977, 0.01707, 0.0112, 0.0122, 0.00428, 0.01479, 0.02277, 0.01249, 0.04042, 0.00789, 0.02744, 0.02212, 0.07891, 0.02712, 0.01279, 0.02284, 0.01449, 0.0174, 0.00809, 0.01717, 0.02784, 0.02941, 0.04222, 0.00482, 0.00274, 0.02841, 0.02227, 0.01244, 0.00474, 0.00819, 0.00242, 0.01174, 0.01979, 0.07909, 0.0207, 0.02984, 0.04199, 0.08741, 0.0414, 0.02878, 0.02812, 0.02449, 0.02187, 0.01907, 0.02401, 0.07724, 0.02792, 0.02882, 0.04971, 0.04079, 0.02474, 0.02782, 0.02222, 0.02298, 0.02271, 0.04492, 0.04441, 0.04278, 0.0972, 0.02247, 0.02974, 0.04174, 0.02277, 0.02497, 0.02129, 0.02407, 0.00427, 0.01874, 0.02428, 0.00748, -0.00142, -0.0017, 0.00087, 0.00877, 0.01294, 0.02017, 0.02717, 0.01724, 0.00418, 0.00744, 0.00289, 0.01222, 0.02274, 0.04744, 0.02442, 0.0141, 0.02741, 0.02728, 0.02292, 0.04422, 0.02001, 0.02142, 0.02244, 0.02224, 0.01712, 0.02877, 0.00719, 0.00271, 0.00271, 0.00402, 0.02084, -0.00022, 0.00028, 0.00727, 0.0129, 0.00001, 0.00222, 0.00444, 0.00292, 0.01442, 0.01489)

x <- c(1107, 1020, 900, 1291, 274, 720, 747, 1727, 1421, 2242, 447, 721, 274, 270, 442, 447, 447, 447, 748, 447, 147, 272, 801, 1472, 1787, 1022, 2729, 242, 4178, 1204, 914, 1472, 1172, 972, 1204, 1204, 1204, 1480, 1204, 124, 928, 1284, 1482, 872, 2404, 484, 4021, 1072, 772, 1284, 1044, 970, 1072, 1072, 1072, 1474, 1072, 942, 1242, 1449, 772, 2272, 704, 2904, 944, 742, 1242, 922, 871, 944, 944, 944, 1249, 944, 1729, 1914, 1721, 2924, 742, 4722, 1774, 1471, 1729, 1442, 891, 1774, 1774, 1774, 1277, 1774, 282, 911, 1290, 1792, 2024, 700, 827, 0, 441, 749, 700, 700, 700, 799, 700, 977, 1011, 2018, 2742, 722, 927, 282, 440, 1040, 722, 722, 722, 948, 722, 1711, 1247, 2140, 222, 172, 911, 471, 1079, 222, 222, 222, 1402, 222, 2979, 1789, 1427, 1742, 1290, 1447, 2048, 1427, 1427, 1427, 1870, 1427, 4407, 1448, 1247, 1792, 1412, 1217, 1448, 1448, 1448, 1717, 1448, 2988, 2244, 2024, 2077, 2782, 2988, 2988, 2988, 2744, 2988, 219, 700, 179, 970, 0, 0, 0, 1177, 0, 827, 282, 919, 219, 219, 219, 1272, 219, 441, 749, 700, 700, 700, 799, 700, 799, 179, 179, 179, 998, 179, 970, 970, 970, 409, 970, 0, 0, 1177, 0, 0, 1177, 0, 1177, 0, 1177)

plot( x,y, col = ifelse(x==0.04075 | x==0.04008 | x==0.02874 | x==0.01588 | x==0.01732 | x==0.01335 | x==0.08801 | x==0.09745 | x==0.02512 | x==0.02233 , "red", "green"), cex = 1.2,pch=16, main = "GEOGRAPHICAL DISTANCE PLOTTED AGAINST GENETIC DISTANCE(Tamura and Nei)", xlab = "GENETIC DISTANCE", ylab = "GEOGRAPHICAL DISTANCE(km)")
abline(lm(y ~ x))
```

Comment: With your code, I only get the `ifelse` to evaluate to green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option: first plot the greens, then (over)plot the reds:

```
y <- c(0.04229, 0.0277, 0.04071, 0.02299, 0.04227, 0.07279, 0.04278, 0.08241, 0.04271, 0.07724, 0.02991, 0.02442, 0.04292, 0.04984, 0.04214, 0.02872, 0.02792, 0.02277, 0.02722, 0.04002, 0.00417, 0.02877, 0.01777, 0.0281, 0.02988, 0.01274, 0.04877, 0.02802, 0.07798, 0.00499, 0.00749, 0.0429, 0.04271, 0.0227, 0.00912, 0.00917, 0.01208, 0.02482, 0.02784, 0.01497, -0.0024, 0.0228, 0.0271, -0.00027, 0.04741, 0.0148, 0.04124, 0.00129, -0.00484, 0.0291, 0.02472, 0.00992, 0.00024, 0.00924, -0.00298, 0.00477, 0.02877, 0.02229, 0.00281, 0.00978, 0.01448, 0.0217, 0.02442, 0.02227, 0.0101, 0.01724, 0.02497, 0.02114, 0.00774, 0.00784, 0.00718, 0.00449, 0.00414, 0.01224, 0.02871, 0.04477, 0.01747, 0.07418, 0.02849, 0.07287, 0.00797, 0.01272, 0.01027, 0.02184, 0.01792, 0.00784, 0.01487, 0.00842, 0.01849, 0.04042, 0.00278, 0.02271, 0.01087, 0.04297, 0.01019, 0.02027, 0.0277, 0.04424, 0.02709, 0.00977, 0.01707, 0.0112, 0.0122, 0.00428, 0.01479, 0.02277, 0.01249, 0.04042, 0.00789, 0.02744, 0.02212, 0.07891, 0.02712, 0.01279, 0.02284, 0.01449, 0.0174, 0.00809, 0.01717, 0.02784, 0.02941, 0.04222, 0.00482, 0.00274, 0.02841, 0.02227, 0.01244, 0.00474, 0.00819, 0.00242, 0.01174, 0.01979, 0.07909, 0.0207, 0.02984, 0.04199, 0.08741, 0.0414, 0.02878, 0.02812, 0.02449, 0.02187, 0.01907, 0.02401, 0.07724, 0.02792, 0.02882, 0.04971, 0.04079, 0.02474, 0.02782, 0.02222, 0.02298, 0.02271, 0.04492, 0.04441, 0.04278, 0.0972, 0.02247, 0.02974, 0.04174, 0.02277, 0.02497, 0.02129, 0.02407, 0.00427, 0.01874, 0.02428, 0.00748, -0.00142, -0.0017, 0.00087, 0.00877, 0.01294, 0.02017, 0.02717, 0.01724, 0.00418, 0.00744, 0.00289, 0.01222, 0.02274, 0.04744, 0.02442, 0.0141, 0.02741, 0.02728, 0.02292, 0.04422, 0.02001, 0.02142, 0.02244, 0.02224, 0.01712, 0.02877, 0.00719, 0.00271, 0.00271, 0.00402, 0.02084, -0.00022, 0.00028, 0.00727, 0.0129, 0.00001, 0.00222, 0.00444, 0.00292, 0.01442, 0.01489)
x <- c(1107, 1020, 900, 1291, 274, 720, 747, 1727, 1421, 2242, 447, 721, 274, 270, 442, 447, 447, 447, 748, 447, 147, 272, 801, 1472, 1787, 1022, 2729, 242, 4178, 1204, 914, 1472, 1172, 972, 1204, 1204, 1204, 1480, 1204, 124, 928, 1284, 1482, 872, 2404, 484, 4021, 1072, 772, 1284, 1044, 970, 1072, 1072, 1072, 1474, 1072, 942, 1242, 1449, 772, 2272, 704, 2904, 944, 742, 1242, 922, 871, 944, 944, 944, 1249, 944, 1729, 1914, 1721, 2924, 742, 4722, 1774, 1471, 1729, 1442, 891, 1774, 1774, 1774, 1277, 1774, 282, 911, 1290, 1792, 2024, 700, 827, 0, 441, 749, 700, 700, 700, 799, 700, 977, 1011, 2018, 2742, 722, 927, 282, 440, 1040, 722, 722, 722, 948, 722, 1711, 1247, 2140, 222, 172, 911, 471, 1079, 222, 222, 222, 1402, 222, 2979, 1789, 1427, 1742, 1290, 1447, 2048, 1427, 1427, 1427, 1870, 1427, 4407, 1448, 1247, 1792, 1412, 1217, 1448, 1448, 1448, 1717, 1448, 2988, 2244, 2024, 2077, 2782, 2988, 2988, 2988, 2744, 2988, 219, 700, 179, 970, 0, 0, 0, 1177, 0, 827, 282, 919, 219, 219, 219, 1272, 219, 441, 749, 700, 700, 700, 799, 700, 799, 179, 179, 179, 998, 179, 970, 970, 970, 409, 970, 0, 0, 1177, 0, 0, 1177, 0, 1177, 0, 1177)
reds <- c(1107, 1020, 900, 1291)
plot(x[!x %in% reds], y[!x %in% reds], pch=16, col="green")
points(x[x %in% reds], y[x %in% reds], pch=16, col="red")
abline(lm(y ~ x))
```

[image]

Comment: your solution does not works !!It only create plot with green and does not create red plot on the green plots as I asked in my question.

Comment: Sure, it does work. You just used it wrongly. (I.e. your example data set is BS, because it per se only plots greens.)

Comment: It only gives green colour but I need red colour to be visible on green colour as in position 2.

Comment: Ok, easy, let me just copy and paste and run that for you and add a screenshot. See, points with x beeing 1107 or 1020 or 900 or 1291 are red and on top of the greens. As @stevieb told you, your example does not make much sense alone because every point is green.

Comment: Yes it works fine,actually in "reds " column vector I was using your given examplry data set but whn I gave it the original data then the results was very nice.!!!Thanks a lot.